# Debian Server Security

Tags: linux, apache, security, webserver, debian

Few questions in one. I'm a mobile developer, and as a pet project I've set up a small server (on a raspberry pi) that I use as my backend development sever

I think I have set up the server fairly securely and have avoid the common blunders.

The problem is when it comes to security I'm completely neurotic, not because I have something to hide, but because I don't want to be victim of my own naivety / stupidity.

Currently I check my apache2 logs daily to find out what traffic (bar my own) has hit the server. Every day there seems to be between 4-5 hits from random ip's looking for directories that dont exist. Am I correct in assuming there are servers that randomly trawl through ip's searching for known weaknesses in sever software?

My main question is, is there a way for me to log every hit to the server in an sql database? That way I can see if somebody is really trying to get in by querying the number of hits from that ip without trawling through the logs manually.

Secondly, anybody got any more obscure security tips / things I should do on a daily basis?

Thanks for your time!

Edit: - Also, are their any good automatic penetration tools out there that can tell me if I have any vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming there are servers that randomly trawl through ip's searching for known weaknesses in sever software?

Yes.

> My main question is, is there a way for me to log every hit to the server in an sql database?

You could use mod_log_sql: http://www.outoforder.cc/projects/apache/mod_log_sql/

> anybody got any more obscure security tips / things I should do on a daily basis?

you could setup a firewall, use port knocking, expose services only locally and connect via VPN, ...

Comment: Thanks for this, I've got a firewall up and running, I'll set my database to local access only. Is there an advantage to accessing the server via VPN as opposed to SSH? The servers headless so I access it over SSH anyway. Thanks again.